# Is there an adjective for "cannot be defended against"?

Tags: adjectives, synonyms

The adjective *indefensible* is commonly used to describe something that cannot be defended, but it applies to the defender, not to the attack itself. I'm wondering if there's a reasonably neutral word for "cannot be defended against". Something in the same spirit as *foolproof*, but less general and without the connotation of being proofed against fools.

For example,

> *I believe it to be bad policy for a game to have an [adjective] move.*

whose meaning is identical to

> *I believe it to be bad policy for a game to have a move that cannot be defended against.*

The term *unavoidable* comes to mind, but strongly implies that whatever is "unavoidable" must happen, whereas the adjective I'm looking for is conditional on an attack that may or may not happen. *Unavoidable* also doesn't imply defense. In the example above, "an unavoidable move" might just as easily refer to a move that can easily be defended against but that must be made at some point.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: W.r.t. your example, 'insurmountable', 'unsurpassable' or 'omnipotent' could all fit.

Comment: In a game specifically, you might refer to such a move as _unblockable_ or perhaps _unbeatable_, _undefeatable_ or even _invincible_, but those would probably not work so well for other contexts. And of course, they don't really mean that there is no way to defend oneself against them—only that there is no way to **successfully** defend oneself against them and actually defeat or block them.

Comment: There is such a word: "dominant". Unfortunately, it's meaning in that sense is restricted to the realm of Game Theory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Unstoppable** ([Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/unstoppable))

> (adjective) that cannot be stopped or surpassed; unbeatable

**Uncontrollable** ([Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/uncontrollable))

> (adjective) incapable of being controlled or restrained

Comment: "Unstopptable" fits quite nicely. In the particular context where this issue came up, the verb _to stop_ unfortunately had another meaning that was inconsistent with "defend", hence "unstoppable" and "unblockable" were both no-gos. But no such quirks would apply in the majority of cases.

Comment: "Unbeatable" might also work.  "Uncontrollable" is ambiguous - who can't control the move, the attacker or his opponent?

Answer (score 8):

Why not *[irresistible](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/irresistible)*

> not able to be resisted or refused; overpowering [*Collins*]

Comment: This fits, consider the paradox statement of 'irresistible force meeting immovable object'.

Comment: It's a good thought, but would "irresistible" not usually require clarification? My understanding is that "irresistible" carries a strong connotation of desire, hence "Joe countered with an irresistible blow." would tend to imply that Joe could not resist delivering the blow, rather than the intended meaning that I could not resist it.

Comment: @COTO - I respectfully disagree: that would be a perverse interpretation of your example sentence. As to whether 'irresistible' conveys a strong connotation of desire is something that is entirely context-dependent. Furthermore, abstract definitions or interpretations are always subject to being adjusted by a concrete context.

Comment: While that is one meaning of *irresistible*, another is that in the paradox [*irresistible force vs. immovable object.*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irresistible_force_paradox)

Comment: @Erik Kowal You're being disagreeable?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - *Plus ça change...*

Comment: 'Killer' is the usual informal descriptor. Though I wouldn't call it 'reasonably neutral' emotively.

Answer (score 7):

Some variant on **counter** could work:

*I believe it to be bad policy for a game to have a move that cannot be* **countered**.
**Uncounterable** moves make for bad games. For any move, there should always exist a **countermove**.

Answer (score 3):

How about [*undeflectable*?](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/undeflectable) *Uncounterable* might be interpreted to mean that the offensive move cannot be retaliated. *Undeflectable* emphasizes that the offensive move cannot be defended against.

Comment: This implies only that it is impervious to a specific subset of defenses, those which deflect the attack. The item could still be defendable by ablation or other attack-absorbing defenses.

Answer (score 1):

I'd argue for [overwhelming](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/overwhelming) in the second sense:

> So great as to render resistance or opposition useless

Answer (score 1):

*I believe it to be bad policy for a game to have a move that cannot be **fended off***.

*I believe it to be bad policy for a game to have an [**unfendable**](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22unfendable%22&biw=516&bih=338&prmd=mivn&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiF3s6sioHLAhVFhhoKHXx2DTwQ_AUICygG) move*.

> fend off: to hold someone or something off; to fight someone or something off [FOD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fend+off)

*I believe it to be bad policy for a game to have an [**unblockable**](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/parer) move*

> [unblockable](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22unblockable+move%22&biw=499&bih=327&prmd=visn&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiQusKSkIHLAhVB1RoKHedPCIkQ_AUICygG): not blockable; that cannot be blocked [Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/unblockable)

*I believe it to be bad policy for a game to have an **unparryable** move*

> unparryable: impossible to [parry](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/parry); difficult to ward off [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/unparryable)

Answer (score 0):

Ineluctable?

"unable to be resisted or avoided; inescapable"

Comment: If your quote is quoted from somewhere, please use the [> Markdown syntax](http://english.stackexchange.com/editing-help) and you **must** [say where it comes from](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).

Answer (score 0):

How about [*inescapable*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inescapable)?

> I believe it to be bad policy for a game to have an inescapable move.

Answer (score 0):

"Indefensible". This is usually used to describe the thing (not) being defended ("an indefensible argument"), but is also valid to describe the thing being defended against ("an indefensible attack"), with context distinguishing the two.

Answer (score -1):

Irrefutable could fit in your context.
Indisputable, Unquestionable, undeniable also seem to be fine

Answer (score -2):

unstoppable, uncounterable,unbeatable,

Answer (score -3):

Why not simply bend the spoon backwards and use a new, invented word like "undefendable"?

Comment: Because *undefendable* (or *indefensible*) means "cannot be defended", not "cannot be defended **aganist**". The OP wants a word to describe the attack, not its object.

Comment: @AndrewLeach That's true of "undefendable", but "indefensible" is used with somewhat more versatility, perhaps because its deconstruction more vaguely implies non-association with a defense, whereas the deconstruction for "undefendable" is rather less ambiguous.